# How could I change the height of a component that inside a div by @media?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that contains an image and I want to change the height of this image without changing the div.

**html:**

```
<div class="tik1 fill col ">
     <img class="ffdsg" src="images/jb.png"  alt="">
</div>
```

css:

```
height: 300px;
width: 350px;
position: relative;
border-radius: 20px;
margin-left: 20%;
margin-right: 70px;
margin-top:100px;
```

Comment: Please elaborate more what's the issue, I mean if you want to access the img element in css you can use the class selector or you can use .tik1 > img:first-child to do the same thing.

Comment: You would be better served if you show how you attempted the `@media`, which height you wish to set depending on which media height, min or max height etc. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/height

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS select `img` tag and set height that you want

```
img {
  height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Your answer does not seem to indicate any reference to the `@media` from the question title

Answer (score 0):

I believe you seek something like this to detect the device height and set that of the image:

```
/* At the top level of your CSS code */
@media screen and (height: 360px) {
  .ffdsg {
    height: 200px;
  }
}
```

Reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/height